# Spring XD Processing files

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

We have a requirement where we need to process multiple files from a folder (each file having 50K-100K records) and after doing some calculation store the data in database. Once the content of the file is processed then we need to trigger a second stream to do some further processing.

The way we have designed the solution is

File Reader -- File Splitter -- Processor -- Re-sequencer (release strategy per record) -- Sink (Load Data in Database)

The issue with the above design is from re-sequencer and Sink we are not able to figure out if all the contents of a file are successfully stored in database without which we cannot invoke the second stream.

We have done some benchmark activities with aggregator and it seems to be much slower than re-sequencer. Are there any known performance issues with aggregator? Are there any serious performance degradation if we have a release strategy of releasing only when all the data is with re-sequencer

Thanks,
Jayadeep

Processor 1 - Splits the lines

```
Processor 2 - Calculation on each message
<int:service-activator input-channel="input" ref="singlePointCalculator" method="onMessage"/>
<bean id="singlePointCalculator" class="com.processor.SinglePointCalculator">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="output"/>

</bean>

Sink

<int:resequencer input-channel='input' output-channel='reseqChannel' release-strategy-expression="size() == 1" ></int:resequencer>

<int:transformer ref="mapTransformer" input-channel="reseqChannel" output-channel="mapChannel"/>

<bean id="mapTransformer" class="com.sink.MapTransformer">
<property name="columns" value=" side,value" />
</bean>

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
                data-source="dataSource"
                channel="mapChannel"
                query=" ">
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>


Sink Using Aggregator

<int:aggregator input-channel='input' output-channel='aggChannel' " ></int:aggregator >
<int:transformer ref="mapTransformer" input-channel="aggChannel" output-channel="mapChannel"/>

<bean id="mapTransformer" class="com.sink.MapTransformer">
<property name="columns" value=" side,value" />
</bean>

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
                data-source="dataSource"
                channel="mapChannel"
                query=" ">
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Can you show your aggregator configuration? Specifically are you using an externally-declared message store? Also, you may want to use a processor to store the data and send a message to some other sink when the data is stored.

Comment: @Gary - I have mentioned the code snippet. We are trying to store the data in Gemfire XD database. The problem we are trying to solve is somehow be aware when all the records in a file are successfully stored in database, only then trigger the next stream. Could you please provide some sample of processor storing data and then sending message to a sink for such a usecase

Comment: Make `mapChannel` a `publish-subscribe-channel`, set `order="1"` on the jdbc adapter add a `<transformer/>` as a second subscriber (`order="2"`) to transform the payload to something like 'stored ok'. And set the transformer's output channel to `output`. The transformer will only be invoked if the store is successful.

Comment: Thanks @Gary will try this out and let you know...